# Xamarin - GoogleMap class move to specific location

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin

In Xamarin's inbuilt `Map` class, you can use the `Map.MoveToRegion(New Position(latitude, longitude))` function to go to an area on the map. I am using the `GoogleMap` nuget package, and can't seem to find a similar in built function. Is there a function for this with the `GoogleMap` plugin, and if so, what is it?

```
GoogleMap gMap = new GoogleMap();
//gMap.MoveToRegion(New Position(34.9820, 138.5160)); <-- something like this
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move the region use below code where

```
gMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(Latitude, Longitude), Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Distance.FromMiles(5)));
```

and use moveCamera to fit two points to bounds(phone screen)

```
var bounds = Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Bounds.FromPositions(gMap.Polylines.SelectMany(poly => poly.Positions));
                    var newBoundsArea = CameraUpdateFactory.NewBounds(bounds, 5);
                    await gMap.MoveCamera(newBoundsArea);
```

Where 5 is padding.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the camera

```
var latlng = new LatLng(34.9820, 138.5160);
gMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(latlng));
```