# How to add pinpoint and display current position on google map

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a simple geolocation app in Xamarin which shows me the user’s current coordinates. I would like to update my application so that after pressing a button, the coordinates will be displayed on a map and show the current location. I am using the Xamarin Essentials plugin.

```cs
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  try
  {
    var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
    if (location == null)
    {
      location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
      {
        DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
      });
    }

    if (location == null)
      LabelLocation.Text = "No GPS";
    else
      LabelLocation.Text = $"{ location.Latitude } { location.Longitude }";

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine($"something isnt working: {ex.Message}");
  }

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

Comment: I added google map to aplication. Now i have problem how to show current user location when i press the button

Comment: use geolocation to find the current location, then move the map to that location.  This is all explained in the documentation

Comment: In your MAP XAML put this `IsShowingUser="true"`

Answer (score 0):

> Now i have problem how to show current user location when i press the
>   button

After you get the current location, you can use [Map.MoveToRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map#move-the-map) to go to current position in the map.

```
private async void Button_Clicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
        if (location == null)
        {
            location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
            {
                DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
            });
        }


        if (location == null)
            LabelLocation.Text = "No GPS";
        else
            LabelLocation.Text = $"{ location.Latitude } { location.Longitude }";

        yourMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Distance.FromMiles(5)));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"something isnt working: {ex.Message}");
    }

}
```

Refer : [move-to-specific-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156463/xamarin-googlemap-class-move-to-specific-location) and [implementing-google-map-in-xamarin-forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-google-map-in-xamarin-forms/)